Why I get undefined? I need help. Thank you
const users = { user1: 18273, user2: 92833, user3: 90315 }

//Answer
const usersArray = Object.entries(users).map((keys, value)=> {return keys[0] + ' ' + value[1]});
console.log(usersArray);

//OUTPUT:
 ['user1 undefined', 'user2 undefined', 'user3 undefined']

I expect it to be like this:
 [ [ 'user1', 18273 ], [ 'user2', 92833 ], [ 'user3', 90315 ] ]


Just Object.entries(users) will give you your expected output. No need to map.

Have you used a debugger or console.log to see what the value is whose value[0] you are accessing?

value[0], not value[1]

You should begin by doing console.log(Object.entries(users)) to see where you're starting from.  You might be surprised at what you see.  Better yet, read the documentation.

Furthermore, your usage of .map is inappropriate.  The predicate is not being passed (keys, value), but rather (entry, index)   Each entry is an array defined by Object.entries and according to the documentation: the first element is the property key (which is always a string), and the second element is the property value.  (just like in your expected output, actually) And the predicate's second argument is the index of the element that is being processed.  and will be 0, 1, 2, etc... for each successive element being mapped.

this should work

const users = { user1: 18273, user2: 92833, user3: 90315 }
const usersArray = Object.entries(users).map((user) => ([user[0], user[1]]));
console.log(usersArray);



It would be much helpful if you can add some description. How this code gonna work.

.map((user) => ([user[0], user[1]])); is a waste of effort. Object.entries(users) alone produces the expected output.

I agree with the example above, now the explanation.
Undefined reason:
The map function expects two arguments in the callback function: keys (the array of key-value pairs) and value (the index of the current element in the original array). In your code, you are using value as if it contained the user ID, but it actually refers to the second index of the keys array, which is always undefined.
To fix this, access the user ID from index 1 of the keys array:
const usersArray = Object.entries(users).map(keys => keys[0] + ' ' + keys[1]);

now for the output format to be:
[ [ 'user1, 18273' ], [ 'user2, 92833' ], [ 'user3, 90315' ] ]

you simply set the return to []:
const usersArray = Object.entries(users).map(keys => [keys[0] + ' ' + keys[1]]);


This does not match the output that the OP expected.
